# あなたのために綺麗になりたいと願う / 好きな人の前では女の子でいたい

Tags: parsing, song-lyrics

> あなたのために綺麗になりたいと願う
> 好きな人の前では女の子でいたい ([full lyrics here](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Azusa:%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AB))

> For your sake, I want to become a girl that hopes to become pretty in front of the person I love

Does that feel too convoluted to you, or am I parsing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

願う is not modifying anything. Parse this line simply as two sentences.

> あなたのために綺麗になりたいと願う。好きな人の前では女の子でいたい。
>   I wish to become beautiful for you.
>   In front of someone I like, I want to be a girl (i.e. to be seen as a girl).